# Pandas: How to convert datetime objects into float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Running the MRE below gives me the following output:

```
            c1                     c2                 c3
0 2023-11-12 10:36:00    2023-11-12 03:00:00    0 days 07:36:00
1 2023-11-12 00:41:00    2023-11-11 00:00:00    1 days 00:41:00
```

```
import pandas as pd

lines = [
    "2023-11-12T10:36:00\t2023-11-12T03:00:00",
    "2023-11-12T00:41:00\t2023-11-11T00:00:00"
]
data = pd.DataFrame([l.split('\t') for l in lines], columns=['c1', 'c2'])
data["c1"] = pd.to_datetime(data["c1"])
data["c2"] = pd.to_datetime(data["c2"])
data["c3"] = data["c1"] - data["c2"]
print(data)
```

What I want to see in the third column are 7.36 and 24.41, respectively. I tried using:

```
data["c3"] = (data["c1"] - data["c2"]).dt.total_seconds() / 3600.0
```

however this ends up with the following incorrect result:

```
            c1                     c2              c3
0 2023-11-12 10:36:00    2023-11-12 03:00:00    7.600000
1 2023-11-12 00:41:00    2023-11-11 00:00:00    24.683333
```

Comment: How do you get 25.41 from `1 days 00:41:00`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. 24.41 it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want minutes to be a fractional part of your number, you can calculate hours and minutes separately:

```
data["hours"] = data["c3"].dt.total_seconds() // (60 * 60)
data["minutes"] = (data["c3"].dt.total_seconds() - data["hours"] * 60 * 60) / 60 / 100
data["hours"] + data["minutes"]
```

Output:

```
0     7.36
1    24.41
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
data['c3'] = (((data["c1"] - data["c2"]).dt.total_seconds() / 3600.0)
            .map(lambda x: float(f"{int(x)}.{int(round((x-int(x))*60, 0)):02d}")))
```

Output:

```
                   c1                  c2     c3
0 2023-11-12 10:36:00 2023-11-12 03:00:00   7.36
1 2023-11-12 00:41:00 2023-11-11 00:00:00  24.41
```